# How to port Visual Studio 2013 solutions to Visual Studio 2015 such that they are under the VS2015 projects folder

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

So I recently installed VS2015 after having using VS2013 for a bit. I actually only used VS2013 to create one VB.net project, so I would like to abandon VS2013 and use VS2015 exclusively and likely uninstall VS2013

While I was able to open and run this single VS2013 project in VS2015 just fine, I would like to move the VS2013 project over to the VS2015 project directory;  C:\Users\myname\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\projects

How can I best do this?

Comment: Why not just move the files from `Visual Studio 2013\Projects` to `Visual Studio 2015\Projects`?

Answer (score 0):

OK got it. I simply made a copy of the old project under VS2015. Still it showed as a VS2013 project, so (with the project opened in VS2015) I performed "Save As ..." in the "File"-menu and overwrite the existing solution file. Now I can double click on the .sln file and it opens in VS2015